# $http.get code working in browser but not in android device using ionic framework

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, angularjs, cordova

```
var service = angular.module('ionicApp.service', [])

service
    .factory('menuService', function($http) {
        return {
            getMenu: function() {
                return $http.get("/json/menu.json");
            },
        }
    });
```

This code works fine and ajax returns success, but in case when I deploy my app on device using command "cordova run android", same ajax fails.
Here is how I am calling menuService.getMenu() function.

```
menuService.getMenu().then(function(response){
            $scope.menuItems = response.data;
        },
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that application root changes on device, so path `/json/menu.json` doesn't lead to json file anymore. Examine `location` object properties to find out how to construct correct path. Or use relative path. Or set up `base` path.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly i should look for, or how to follow your comment.

Comment: Check `location.pathname` first of all.